# Accessing Angular component variable via Leaflet marker.on('click', ...)

Tags: ngx-leaflet

I'm using ngx-leaflet to render a map in an Angular app. I'm adding markers to a layer with an EventListener on click like so:

```
questions.forEach((question) => {
  this.layers.push(
    marker([question.lat, question.lng], {
      icon: icon({
        iconSize: [25, 41],
        iconAnchor: [13, 41],
        iconUrl: 'assets/marker-icon.png',
        shadowUrl: 'assets/marker-shadow.png'
      })
    }).on('click', this.onClick)
  );
});
```

With onClick being:

```
onClick(e) {
  this.showQuestion = true;
  console.log('data: ', e);
}
```

I want the click on a marker to set the showQuestion Boolean to true, but the context of `this` is not related to the Angular component, but to the Leaflet event.

How can I access the Angular component `this` instead of the Leaflet `this`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use bind to create a function with an explicit `this` context. See the following example:

```
questions.forEach((question) => {
  this.layers.push(
    marker([question.lat, question.lng], {
      icon: icon({
        iconSize: [25, 41],
        iconAnchor: [13, 41],
        iconUrl: 'assets/marker-icon.png',
        shadowUrl: 'assets/marker-shadow.png'
      })
    }).on('click', this.onClick.bind(this))
  );
});
```

In this example, the onClick handler will be invoked with `this` set to whatever `this` is referring to when the call to bind is evaluated (I'm assuming from your example it will be the ngx component).

Comment: Thanks, that's it! I just watched this [course](https://egghead.io/courses/understand-javascript-s-this-keyword-in-depth) but still find `this` confusing.

Comment: Can we pass the click event to the "onClick" method ?
I am trying to display ionic popover near to the marker. Right now it is getting displayed in center by default.
To position it near the marker, the event needs to be passed.